# Practical calculation of Canterbury approximants

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory, multivariable-calculus

I'm looking for references on how to compute Canterbury approximants numerically from a practical point of view. The references on Canterbury approximants that I am aware of all appear rather abstract and theoretical at first glance. Of course it is entirely possible that the theory hasn't reached the point where practical considerations become important (there's little point in arguing about how to best implement an algorithm that might not exist or that tends to give incorrect results), in which case a reference affirming this would also be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old source (it gives code in Fortran), but it might still serve your purpose:
[Calculation of Canterbury approximants](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0010465575900685?via%3Dihub), Computer Physics Communications **10** (1975) 234.

A somewhat more recent source of numerical routines for bivariate Padé approximants of this type is [Subroutine library for partial differential approximants](https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-4655(90)90051-2), Computer Physics Communications **61** (1990) 374.